# python looping through a list of images and merging them in groups

Tags: python, merge

I have a list of images that all are the same dimensions with names such as `patch_i_j.jpg`:
which `i` and `j` increase in steps of 2000.
Now I want to merge images with certain 'i' into one image. And I want to do this for all the `i`s.

I've written this code:

```
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image

    slide='patient_004_node_4'
    levelstr= 'level_2'

    list_im=np.load('D:/.../patch_maskimg_array.npy')
    dim_array='D:/.../dim_array.npy'
    savepath='D:/.../otsu_mask.png'


    mask_dim = np.load(dim_array).tolist()
    a=2000
    x=mask_dim[0]
    y=mask_dim[1]
    xnum=round(x/a)
    ynum=round(y/a)

    list_mat=np.array_split(list_im, xnum)



for i in range(0,y,a):
    k=round(y/a)
    imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in list_mat[k:k+1,:]]
    img_merge = Image.fromarray( imgs)
    savepath='D:/.../otsu_mask_'+str(i)+'.png'
    img_merge.save( savepath )
```

In this part `imgs = [ Image.open(i) for kk in list_im]` how can I say that I want only images from certain index range to merge?

gives me this error:

```
imgs = [ Image.open(i) for i in list_mat[k:k+1,:]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: What is the question here? How to "partition" the list of images into buckets with same dimensions, or how to merge the images?

Comment: yes  How to "partition" the list of images into buckets

Comment: and also in this part imgs = [ Image.open(i) for kk in list_im] how can I say that I want only images from certain index range to merge